# Training error not decreasing on the training set

Tags: regression, neural-networks, supervised-learning, keras

I cannot make my neural network - MLP with 1 hidden layer fit the training data perfectly. Here is the data:

```
xs1 = c(-1, 0, 1)
ys1 = c(-0.2445248, 0.1232554, 0.1713998)
```

This was actually generated by $y = sin(x) + \mathcal{N}(0, 0.25)$ and scaled. The idea is to predict **ys1** perfectly from **xs1** for the training set.

I define an MLP with 1 hidden layer, 10 neurons:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>% 
  layer_dense(10, input_shape = c(1)) %>%
  layer_dense(activation = "linear", units = 1)

model %>% compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = optimizer_adam(lr = 0.00001))
model %>% fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size = 32, epochs = 10000, verbose = 2)
```

So, I would like to have 0 error on this training set. However, this is how convergence looks like:

```
Epoch 1/10000
 - 2s - loss: 0.0084
Epoch 2/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0084
Epoch 3/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0083
Epoch 4/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0082
Epoch 5/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0081
Epoch 6/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0081
Epoch 7/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0080
Epoch 8/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0079
Epoch 9/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0079
Epoch 10/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0078
Epoch 11/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0077
Epoch 12/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0077
Epoch 13/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0076
Epoch 14/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0075
Epoch 15/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0075
Epoch 16/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0074
Epoch 17/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0074
Epoch 18/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0073
Epoch 19/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0073
Epoch 20/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0072
Epoch 21/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0071
Epoch 22/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0071
Epoch 23/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0070
Epoch 24/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0070
Epoch 25/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0070
Epoch 26/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0069
Epoch 27/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0069
Epoch 28/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0068
Epoch 29/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0068
Epoch 30/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0067
Epoch 31/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0067
Epoch 32/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0067
Epoch 33/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0066
Epoch 34/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0066
Epoch 35/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0066
Epoch 36/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0065
Epoch 37/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0065
Epoch 38/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0065
Epoch 39/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0064
Epoch 40/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0064
Epoch 41/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0064
Epoch 42/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0064
Epoch 43/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0063
Epoch 44/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0063
Epoch 45/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0063
Epoch 46/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0063
Epoch 47/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0062
Epoch 48/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0062
Epoch 49/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0062
Epoch 50/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0062
Epoch 51/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0061
Epoch 52/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0061
Epoch 53/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0061
Epoch 54/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0061
Epoch 55/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0061
Epoch 56/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0061
Epoch 57/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0060
Epoch 58/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0060
Epoch 59/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0060
Epoch 60/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0060
Epoch 61/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0060
Epoch 62/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0060
Epoch 63/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0060
Epoch 64/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 65/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 66/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 67/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 68/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 69/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 70/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 71/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 72/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0059
Epoch 73/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 74/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 75/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 76/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 77/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 78/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 79/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 80/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 81/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 82/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 83/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 84/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 85/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 86/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 87/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 88/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0058
Epoch 89/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0057
Epoch 90/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0057
Epoch 91/10000
 - 0s - loss: 0.0057
```

As soon as it reaches 0.0057 it does not move lower. Even if run for 10000 iterations.

I tried to change the learning step from 0.1 to 0.0000001 to no avail - still no progress when it hits 0.0057.

If I change the number of layers or neurons - it simply stops at some other value, but never reaches near 0 (for 2 datapoints it actually produces values around $10^{-15}$). I tried different activations - no use. Still not 0.

Can it be local minimum somehow? But it is only 3 points and 10 hidden units - isn't it a very simple surface that should be easily optimized up to very small values?

What am I doing wrong? Can you get 0 on this dataset with this MLP?

Comment: Why are you using a linear hidden layer?

Comment: I thought it was sigmoid by default ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`layer dense`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kerasR/versions/0.6.1/topics/Dense) method in keras library uses *linear activation* by default, which means between the hidden and output layers, you don't accommodate nonlinear transformations. If you stack layers without nonlinearity in-between them, your neural network will be equivalent to a one-layer neural network. Please check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384966/how-does-nonlinearity-in-neural-networks-find-meaningful-features/385002#385002) for a simple explanation if you're interested.

So, your neural network is actually one-layer, and that is the output neuron, which means we're trying to solve $wx+b=y$. You have the following least squares problem, $Xa=y:$ $$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-0.2445248 \\ 0.1232554 \\ 0.1713998\end{bmatrix}$$
The solution to this linear system is $\hat{a}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. Mean squared error is $\text{MSE}=\frac{1}{3}||y-\hat{y}||^2$, where $\hat{y}=X\hat{a}=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$. When you calculate this, you'll obtain $0.0057$, which is actually your *global optimum*.

Now, put an activation function in the first layer, and watch the system converge to a better optimum.

Comment: Thx a lot! Would have taken me much longer to figure. I thought sigmoid was default in keras dense layer like in lstm. I tried now with sigmoid - and after waiting for a lot of time, the error did indeed budge down.